# How to load Web-Assembly scripts in React Native?

Tags: react-native, webassembly

Is there any way we can load a simple web assembly script in react native app and on click of a button we can call c++/c function inside .wasm file?

A small tutorial will be appreciated!

Comment: did u found an answer?

Comment: No, Instead we shifted on flutter for Hybrid application building.